# Rsync only specific filenames

Tags: linux, backup, rsync

I have a large directory tree and want to copy only files with specific names. I also want to preserve the directory structure, incrementally update, and maintain metadata, so `rsync` seems like the natural choice. However, I can't get the syntax to work correctly. Consider the following example structure:

```
$ find .
.
./filter.txt
./dest
./source
./source/no
./source/fold1
./source/fold1/yes
./source/fold1/no
./source/fold2
./source/fold2/no
./source/fold2/yes
```

So I have a source folder with subfolders and files named `yes` (copy) and `no` (do not copy).  Based on some other questions (eg. https://serverfault.com/questions/770728/rsync-exclude-all-directories-except-a-few) I have been trying to use a filter file that includes files I want but excludes everything else. I have tried several things, but a simple filter file that is not working is:

```
$ cat filter.txt 
+ /fold1/yes
- *

$ rsync -avv --progress --include-from=filter.txt source/ dest/
sending incremental file list
[sender] hiding file no because of pattern *
[sender] hiding directory fold1 because of pattern *
[sender] hiding directory fold2 because of pattern *
delta-transmission disabled for local transfer or --whole-file
total: matches=0  hash_hits=0  false_alarms=0 data=0

sent 59 bytes  received 86 bytes  290.00 bytes/sec
total size is 0  speedup is 0.00
```

Changing the order or using slightly different syntax (eg. `*/yes`, `yes`) do not change anything. In the final implementation, I would like to be able to include all `yes` files without describing their folders, and there are many other files besides `no` so excluding them individually is not a good solution. It seems like the `- *` filter line is excluding everything regardless of whatever has been included above or below it, but that is inconsistent with the other information I've seen.

How can I rsync only specific-named files (in subfolders) while excluding everything else?

I have seen some similar questions but (as discussed above) they do not seem to solve my problem, eg.: https://serverfault.com/questions/770728/rsync-exclude-all-directories-except-a-few https://serverfault.com/questions/1063730/rsync-exclude-all-files-in-dir-except-specific-files.

**Edit 1**
Per @harrymc, a filter that explicitly includes the folder and file works for that file:

```
$ cat filter2.txt 
+ /fold1/
+ /fold1/yes
- *

$ rsync -avv --progress --include-from=filter2.txt source/ dest/
sending incremental file list
[sender] hiding file no because of pattern *
[sender] showing directory fold1 because of pattern /fold1/
[sender] hiding directory fold2 because of pattern *
[sender] showing file fold1/yes because of pattern /fold1/yes
[sender] hiding file fold1/no because of pattern *
delta-transmission disabled for local transfer or --whole-file
[generator] risking file fold1/yes because of pattern /fold1/yes
./
fold1/
fold1/yes
              0 100%    0.00kB/s    0:00:00 (xfr#1, to-chk=0/3)
total: matches=0  hash_hits=0  false_alarms=0 data=0

sent 157 bytes  received 178 bytes  670.00 bytes/sec
total size is 0  speedup is 0.00
```

**Edit 2**
A generic filter that satisfies my needs is, based on the accepted answer:

```
+ */
+ */yes
- *
```

This automatically includes every `yes` file while excluding everything else.

Comment: Try to write `filter.txt` as line 1 : `+ /fold1/`, line2 : `+ /fold1/yes`.

Comment: @harrymc Thanks for the response, see my edit. But I would like to extend that to include all `yes` files without specifically listing `fold1/yes`, `fold2/yes`, and so on. In my real use case I have several types of `yes` files, many `no` files, and many folders.

Comment: @harrymc also, if you could explain/point me in the direction of why `+ /fold1, +/fold1/yes` is different than simply `+/fold1/yes` it might help me build my own solution.

Comment: See if the explanation in my answer can cast some light on the question. Is there a pattern for the `yes`?

Comment: A pattern for `yes` would be `/*/yes`. In the real example, it could be `/*/yes` and `/*/also`: many files all with the same name(s).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The explanation for the problem comes from the confusing message of
"hiding file no because of pattern *".

There is a good explanation found in the post
[rsync --include-from syntax](https://access.redhat.com/discussions/3548881#comment-1335871) :

> If a pattern excludes a particular parent directory, it can render a
> deeper include pattern ineffectual because rsync did not descend
> through that excluded section of the hierarchy.  This is particularly
> important when using a trailing ’*’ rule.  For instance, this won’t
> work:
>
> ```
>           + /some/path/this-file-will-not-be-found
>           + /file-is-included
>           - *
> ```
>
> This fails because the parent directory "some" is excluded by the ’*’
> rule, so rsync never visits any of the files in the "some" or
> "some/path" directories. One solution is to ask for all directories in
> the hierarchy to be included by using a single rule: "+ */" (put it
> somewhere before the "- *" rule), and perhaps  use  the
> --prune-empty-dirs option.  Another solution is to add specific include rules for all the parent dirs that need to be visited.  For
> instance, this set of rules works fine:
>
> ```
>           + /some/
>           + /some/path/
>           + /some/path/this-file-is-found
>           + /file-also-included
>           - *
> ```
>
> You may have to re-define your include file list.

The problem is then that the parent folder `/fold1` is excluded and
needs to be included as well.

By this explanation, the file `filter.txt` needs to be written as :

```
+ /fold1/
+ /fold1/yes
```

Comment: That explanation really helps. So if I want to generalize to many folders (instead of writing out `fold1/`, and so on), I would need to use the `+ */` line?

Comment: Based on this answer, I was able to generalize the function to my specific case - see the second edit to my main question. Thanks!

Comment: Bounty awarded, I was able to get my main problem working with your help.